# Multiple installation configurations for a Python package

Tags: python, packaging, pip, distribute

I'm working on creating a Python package that is somewhat modular in nature and I was wondering what's the best way to go about handling multiple installation configurations?

Take the following `setup.py` for the package of a simple document parser:

```
setup(
    name = 'my_document_parser',
    ...
    entry_points = {
        'my_document_parser.parsers': [
            'markdown = my_document_parser.parsers.misaka:Parser [misaka]',
            'textile = my_document_parser.parsers.textile:Parser [textile]'
        ]
    },
    install_requires = [
        'some_required_package'
    ],
    extras_require = {
        'misaka' = ['misaka'],
        'textile' = ['textile']
    },
    ...
)
```

I'd like to make something like the following available:

- A default install

  - `python setup.py install` or `pip install my_document_parser`
  - installs `my_document_parser`, `some_required_package`, `misaka`
- A bare install

  - something like `python setup.py install --bare`
  - installs `my_document_parser`, `some_required_package`
- A way to enable other dependencies

  - something like `python setup.py install --bare --with-textile`
  - installs `my_document_parser`, `some_required_package`, `textile`

This is my first time messing around with Python packages from a developer standpoint, so I'm open to anything anyone has to offer if I'm going about things the wrong way or such.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The default installation will install everything in your `install_requires` and `packages` sections. Packages under `extras_require` will never be installed by your setup.py script; only if you create some logic for this kind of installation.

By default, `setuptools` and `distutils` have no way to explictly say "install using these sections of my setup call". You would need to implement by yourself.

`pip` always installs packages using **no parameter to setup.py** but *--single-version-externally-managed*, to tell `setuptools` to never create a `.egg` file.

**Conclusion**: if you want people to install your package by using pip, forget `--bare` and `--with-textile`. The best you can do is a full installation including `misaka` and `textile` as dependencies.

Maybe you should read [The Hitchhiker's Guide To Packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/), specifically [Creating a Package](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html) section and [setuptool's specification](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools) -- it is a pretty good one, it covers everything setuptools can do.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but for the most part you just told me everything I already knew and have already read all the links you posted. My example commands were just that, an example of what I'd like to achieve, not what I expected to accomplish with distribute or pip specifically. My question as in the title and first paragraph is: __What's the best way to go about making multiple installation configurations available for a Python package?__

Comment: No problem, I appreciate the response.